# Overlay links on image allowing resizing of image

Tags: html, image, css, layout

I'm attempting to overlay some links on an image. These links trigger popover editable fields but that's irrelevant.

The issue is that I want to be able to allow the image to be sized to fit a user's browser without requiring scrolling. In order to do this, I need the absoloute positioning of the overlaid controls to adjust their position to the scaled image.

At the moment I'm laying things out as so:

```
<div style="position: relative;">
    <!-- the image fill the div for the sake of this example assume img is 1000px square -->
    <img src="bigimg.png">

    <!-- a number of divs like this create links over the image
    <div style="left: 500px; top: 500px; position:absolute;">

        <a style="display:block; width:397px; height:27px;" class="editable editable-click editable-empty">Link Name</a>

    </div>

</div>
```

What would be best option be to automatically adjust the position of the div if the image has a size forced upon it, or is set to fill a specifically sized div.

Eg.
I force the image to be 500x500 instead of 1000x1000. I would need the div to adjust it's position to 250x250 and the  to adjust it's width/height.

Comment: you can use jquery and write function (onload resize), this function will be creating and add position (new) when you change windows size in browser. You can use media queries in css if your idea is not advanced.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to expand upon the comment by @mcmac here is a quick and dirty jquery function that finds the dimensions of your wrapper, then sets its child image to be the same dimensions.  Then it uses those same dimensions to absolutely position a link inside the wrapper, over the image.

```
function resizeImg() {
var container = $('.container'), // this wraps the image and link
    containerH = container.height(),
    containerW = container.width(),
    image = $('.container img'),
    link = $('.link');

image.height(containerH) // set image height to container height
     .width(containerW), // set image width to container width

link.css('left', containerW/2) // move link halfway from left edge of container
    .css('top', containerH/2); // and halfway from top of container
}

$(resizeImg)
```

Here's the HTML I used:

```
<div class="container">
    <img src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/e/ec/Happy_smiley_face.png" />
    <div class="link">
        <a href="http://google.com">Link</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

You would want this function to run not only on document ready (as i have it here with the shorthand `$(resizeImg)`) but also on [resize](http://api.jquery.com/resize/). If you let users manually resize the image's container, look into the [CSS3 resize property](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_resize.asp) and see how that behaves for you.

Here's a **[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/64Md6/1/)**, you can experiment by changing the dimensions of `.container` in the CSS and hitting "run" to see the link reposition itself accordingly.

Two things to note:

- You might want to refine the math of how you move the link around. For instance, to center the link on a pair of coordinates (not just its upper left corner), you would need to subtract 1/2 the height and 1/2 the width from its coordinates. This is all up to you and how you're anchoring them visually. For coord's other than "center", you would need to give the links `top` and `left` properties in CSS, then find those in the jQuery, and do some more math, e.g. if link is at `top:42` and the container shrinks by 1/3 it's height, set `top:14` by dividing 42/3, etc.
- There are many ways to do this whole setup. I'd suggest looking into using the image as a `background-image` property of the wrapper, and not an `<img>` DOM element. This may clean up some spacing issues you're having, or conflicts between your `display` properties that might happen down the road. Responsive frameworks like [jQueryUI](http://jqueryui.com/) and [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/) may have some of what you're looking for built in by default, so give those a look and see what they offer.

Answer (score 0):

As long as you don't set the div to be display:block; you it the width should automatically size to its contents width. If you want to be safe you could set a width:auto;

Comment: A div is, by default, `display: block` which is what allows it to expand to fill up the entire space.